# Catching 403 errors in Angular and showing a pop up

Tags: angularjs, typescript

On our site, I get into this predicament where you basically transfer a project over to another user.  When that happens, if the original user tries to view the project he/she just transferred, we give a 403 back because they no longer are the owner of the project.  I started to look up interceptors in Angular.  I hooked up the responseError to just see if it gets called on the 403 like so

```
.config(($httpProvider) => {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
            return {
                responseError: function(rejection) {
                    console.log("bad response");
                    return rejection;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

So my "bad response" gets called and everything, but I was not sure how I could show a modal view or something at this point that shows the error to the user since this 403 response actually happens on a few of our different resources, not just projects.

Comment: You want it to show up only for specific http calls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If i understand correctly you want to show the error dialog only for some http calls not every call that goes through you interceptor. You could probably try this:-

Set a config for your http calls  say `handleError:true`.

```
$http.get('myurl', {handleError:true})....


$http.post('myurl',data, {handleError:true})....
```

etc..

and in your interceptor look for that specific config setting to display the error:-

```
   $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
        return {
            responseError: function(rejection) {
                console.log("bad response");
                if(rejection.config.handleError && rejection.status === 403){
                    //show error dialog
                }
                return rejection;
            }
        }
    });
```

Also you could possibly send the status code that needs to be handled as well.

```
 $http.get('myurl', {handleStatus:[403,...]})....
```

and

```
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
        return {
            responseError: function(rejection) {
                if((rejection.config.handleStatus || []).indexOf(rejection.status) > -1){
                    //show error dialog. probably you could show it in a $timeout to make this async.
                }
                return rejection;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: @P_S_L It will be same for `$resourceProvider` or different?